# Deactivate user after logout in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am trying to deactivate user once user is logout from the system.

I am facing the error

```
You cannot deactivate the user you're currently logged in as.
```

Is there any way to deactivate the user once user is logout from the system.

Comment: But why you want to deactivate it i am not getting you case?

Comment: @VikiChavada I am restrict the user to logout from the system, If user is logout it self, he/she must be re-activate from admin only.

Comment: What method do you call and where do you call it? It's just a guess but It's probably due to use of "uid" instead of "SUPERUSER_ID".

Answer (score 2):

When your user is logged in and she logs out the function `odoo.addons.web.controllers.main.session.logout` is invoked. Try overriding that function to perform your change. It should work, use `sudo()` as well so that you do not get any errors.